# Нужно ли отвечать на вопросы, заданные достаточно давно?

Tags: предложение, вопросы, хэшкод

Иногда попадаются неактуальные вопросы, заданные несколько лет назад (да и полгода много). В итоге многие отвечают на вопрос, не глядя, когда он задан.
Естественно, есть и такие вопросы, ответы к которым можно улучшать, но не все поголовно.

Предлагаю такие вопросы как-то помечать или выделять цветом, чтобы отличать от свежих. Есть в SO средства для этого?

Comment: Тоже озабочен такой проблемой.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На старые вопросы тоже иногда надо отвечать. Это нормальный процесс. Например, если у языка или какая-то другого средства программирования появилась новая возможность, которая упрощает решение, или же прежнее решение по какой-то причине устаревает, то об этом важно написать.

Для отлавливания ответов новичков на старые вопросы существует отдельная очередь ревью, которая доступна для пользователей 1К+: [Запоздалые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers). Некачественные ответы обязательно будут замечены и удалены.

Для обладателей 2К+ репы доступен список всех ответов на старые вопросы: [Новые ответы на вопросы, созданные более 30 дней тому назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions). Каких-то действий этот инструмент не предполагает, но можно пользоваться для слежения.

Ну и как правильно заметил @VladD, всплывание множества старых вопросов — временное явление.

Answer (score 11):

**Если можете ответить — отвечайте. Это будет очень хорошо.**

На эти вопросы можно и нужно отвечать, особенно если

- Вопрос хорошо задан, либо его можно привести к хорошему виду с помощью правки
- Вопрос затрагивает важную тему и по нему можно дать хорошие ответы
- Вопрос имеет много просмотров. Очевидно, что на него часто попадают из поисковиков и он востребован. Кстати, это сильно повышает шансы на то, что ваш ответ тоже будут часто просматривать и ставить плюсы.

В настоящий момент есть достаточно большая масса старых неотвеченных вопросов (порядка <s>16000</s> 14500) Конечно, далеко не все они отвечаемы. Но в общей массе «песка» есть достаточно скрытых золотых самородков.

Специально для того, чтобы дополнительно стимулировать ответы на такие вопросы, придуманы два знака:

[image: Возрождение и Некромант]

Кстати, я [получил Некроманта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=181472) за вот этот самый ответ. :)

**На основном сайте**

[Вопросы, на которых уже можно получить знак «Возрождение»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20votes%3a1..%20isanswered%3ano%20answers%3a0%20created%3a..1m). (исключая вопросы с рейтингом ≤0)

[Вопросы, на которых больше шансов получить знак «Некромант»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20votes%3a1..%20isanswered%3ano%20%20created%3a..2m) (исключая отвеченные и вопросы с рейтингом ≤0)
).

**На Мете (если уж вы увлеклись коллекционированием знаков)**

[Вопросы, на которых уже можно получить знак «Возрождение»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano+answers%3A0+created%3A..1m+-[bug]+-[status-completed]). (Старше 1 месяца, 0 ответов, исключая [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) и [bug](/questions/tagged/bug))

[Вопросы, на которых больше шансов получить знак «Некромант»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3Ano++created%3A..2m+-[bug]+-[status-completed]) (Старше 2 месяцев, неотвеченные, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) и [bug](/questions/tagged/bug))
).

Answer (score 8):

Мне кажется, это не так страшно, если на некровопросы будут даны ответы, в конце-концов, мы — the база знаний.

Конечно, вследствие переезда многие старые вопросы поднимаются (из-за ревью и тому подобного), со временем проблема будет менее остра.

Плохо может быть лишь то, что даются избыточные ответы. Но они не поднимутся вверх (а если они хорошие, то поднимутся, и от этого хуже не будет).

В общем, мне кажется что всё в порядке.

Comment: Речь не об этом. Вопрос в том, можно ли выделитьдавние вопросы значком, цветом или как-то еще.

Comment: @maotm: Мне кажется, не стоит, т. к. проблемы по сути нет.

Comment: @VladD, те ответы, которые я вижу, очень печальны. Обычно поднимается вопрос трехлетней давности, на который дается трехстрочный ответ, относящийся вообще к смежной области.

Comment: @Etki: Вот это и есть проблема: плохие ответы :-) С ними надо так же, как и с плохими ответами на свежие вопросы.