# Обеспечение мотивации отвечать на старые неотвеченные вопросы

Tags: предложение, неотвеченные-вопросы

Не раз приходилось читать, что основной целью Stack Overflow является не помощь отдельным конкретным пользователям, а создание базы знаний. В таком случае нет разницы, каков срок вопроса, на который даётся ответ.

Есть предложение как-либо заинтересовать сообщество отвечать на оставшиеся без ответа длительное время старые вопросы. Например, конкурсами с призами в виде значков и баллов репутации, подобно регулярно проводящимся в Википедии по улучшению коротких или некачественных статей. О деталях их проведения уже можно говорить, если кому-то тут моя идея покажется имеющей смысл.

Отвечать, разумеется, на вопросы, полезные и/или интересные кому-то кроме их автора. Сегодня решил проверить, каков процент таковых, просмотрев историю вопросов по метке [sublime-text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublime-text), попутно отвечая. По моему мнению, процент довольно высок, а [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/213387/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-sublime-text/513322#513322), [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437840/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-autocomplete-%D0%B2-sublime-text-3/513202#513202) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435917/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-sublime-text-3-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-side-bar/513223#513223) мои ответы могут быть полезны многим пользователям Sublime Text.

Comment: значки уже есть

Comment: ну и Дух сообщества подкидывает старье без ответов на главную периодически

Comment: @Grundy, имелись в виду значки или прочие награды за места в конкурсах. Спасибо.

Comment: @Nofate, **Дух сообщества подкидывает также и старье с ответами**, но автор вопроса уже сто лет как забыл в сообщество дорогу и не может/не хочет пометить один из ответов как верный. И Дух ситуацию тут не исправит.

Comment: @MiKeBu, да. и как это противоречит моему высказыванию?

Comment: @MiKeBu да ничего страшного, ответ и так наплюсуют. А иногда и автор заходит, один мой ответ на двухлетней давности вопрос приняли.

Comment: @Nofate, никак не противоречит. Просто Дух делает дурную работу - поднимает вопросы, на которые дали ответ (иногда толковый), но не пометили отвеченным. Хотя, это, наверное, отдельная тема)

Comment: А по данной теме - может стоит научить Духа открывать конкурсы на эн репутации при 1) длительной "неотвеченности" вопроса и 2) превышении порога голосов "за"+"избранное" (показатель интереса)

Answer (score 3):

Цитирую [свой же старый ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/990/181472):

Специально для того, чтобы дополнительно стимулировать ответы на такие вопросы, придуманы два знака:

[image: Возрождение и Некромант]

В целом, далеко не все старые неотвеченные вопросы хороши. Неспроста же они так долго не получают ответа. Возможно, проблему сложно воспроизвести. Или положительного ответа просто нет. ("Как сделать А в Б? А никак.").

Если какой-то старый неотвеченный вопрос действительно хорош, лучше всего будет назначить награду именно за этот конкретный вопрос. Если не хватает своей репутации, можно обратиться в чат, возможно там найдётся меценат. В любом случае перед объявлением конкурса вопрос стоит привести в порядок - поставить нужные метки, отформатировать, уточнить неоднозначные формулировки.

Comment: _Оффтоп_. Фактически находились такие «меценаты»? Если здесь ещё получается набирать репутацию, в крайнем случае исправляя вопросы с орфографическими/пунктуационными ошибками или уточняя неинформативные заголовки, то на англоязычном SO зарабатывать баллы сложнее. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных ну я раза четыре ставил награду за вопрос, который лично мне совсем неинтересен. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin?tab=bounties

Comment: @СашаЧерных На большом СО набирать репу даже проще, просто там надо быть более расторопным, а здесь более упёртым. За правки там тоже можно получать репу, но это может служить мотивацией разве что при очень низкой репе. Меценаты обычно возникают, когда кому-то нужен ответ на старый вопрос. Ради забавы конкурсы раздаёт меньшинство. Впрочем, если кому-то нужен конкурс, а репы нет, то желающего поделиться всегда можно найти. P. S. На СО использование подписей не рекомендуется, это визуальный мусор.