# Как поступать с простыми и наивными вопросами?

Tags: обсуждение

Вчера, имея несколько свободных минут, зашёл на SO.
Открыл первый попавшийся вопрос из новых - он оказался лёгким.
Долго не думая, без какой-либо задней мысли написал ответ.

Потом задумался: "А правильно ли я поступил?"

Первая мысль была следующей:

**Стоило ли мне отвечать на простой вопрос или же лучше было бы его оставить новичкам?**
Ведь если опытные участники сообщества будут отвечать на все лёгкие вопросы, то новичкам мало что останется. Сложные вопросы они не потянут и обновлять каждую минуту страницу в надежде заполучить простой вопрос они тоже не будут: активными участниками сообщества они ещё не стали и пока что даже не знают хотят они этого или нет...и остаётся надеяться на звёзды, чтобы нужный человек оказался в нужное время в нужном месте и в итоге примкнул к нашему сообществу.

**С другой стороны** у всех у нас ограниченное количество времени и отвечая на простой вопрос, возможно **я лишаю кого-то ответа на вопрос более сложный**, но тем не менее мне подсильный.

Но не всё так просто.
Конечно, я могу вопрос оставить на откуп новичкам.
Я не сомневаюсь, что новичок сможет правильно ответить на вопрос, однако с большой степенью вероятности ответ более опытного коллеги будет гораздо точнее, информативнее и качественнее. Он сможет описать причинно-следственные связи, подсказать более подходящие решения, развеять заблуждения и много ещё чего.
**Ответ скорее всего будет качественнее и это ли не главное?**
Насколько для сайта приоритетно качество контента?
Я видел как ребята, обсуждая вопрос с дюжиной, бросающихся в глаза, явных ошибок оперировали такими вещами "а может быть...а что если?..а Вы пробовали?.."
Я сомневаюсь, что в итоге получился бы качественный ответ, потому что помощники сами недалеко ушли...

Пример#2: я увидел простой вопрос, мог на него ответить, но решил проигнорировать.
Спустя время никаких изменений в нём не увидел и в итоге я начал отвечать сам. Когда я заканчивал ответ появились комментарии...это были те ребята, о которых я говорил чуть выше...на этот раз по-моему я поступил правильно!

В общем палка о двух концах.

И в конце мне пришла в голову совершенно ужасная мысль:
**А нужен ли был вообще мой ответ сообществу и принесёт ли он кому-нибудь ещё пользу?**
Ответ состоял в разжёвывании сообщения об ошибке и я не представляю какая у него ценность...
Сам вопрос: 
[ERROR 1064 в MySQL Workbench при создании таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616479/error-1064-%D0%B2-mysql-workbench-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B/616501)

Возможно стоило ответить в комментарии и по истечению какого-то времени почистить его?
...конечно у меня таких привилегий нет), но хотелось бы знать насколько приемлимо отвечать в комментариях на вопросы и что потом с ними случается?

А как Вы поступаете с простыми вопросами?

---

**UPD:**

С данным вопросом тесно связано следующее обсуждение: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).
Однако, несмотря на то, что многие отмечают безусловную схожесть вопросов, я не считаю их дубликатами и (что гораздо важнее для меня) это обсуждение не решило моего вопроса.

И сейчас я объясню почему:

Мотивов вышеуказанного обсуждения было "скатывание" SO. Обсуждались цели ресурса и его проблемы(в частности большое количество новичков и простых вопросов). Автор сомневался в целесообразности практики помощи в простых вопросах и основным мотивом ответов было: "простым вопросам быть!".

В то же время при написании своего вопроса я ни капли не сомневался в том, что простые вопросы должны быть на SO и что они приносят пользу не только студентам, но и опытным специалистам, которые решили освоить новую технологию.

Главным вопросом для меня была внутренняя мотивация, а не цели проекта. Точнее стратегия, при которой я бы приносил максимальную пользу сообществу. И простые вопросы обсуждались в разрезе эффективности отдельно взятого члена сообщества.

Я не спрашивал нужны ли сообществу простые вопросы - я спрашивал что мне нужно сделать чтобы оно стало лучше!

В моём вопросе был один момент, в котором я говорил о том, что сомневаюсь в пользе моего ответа на простой вопрос, однако, этот момент касался воспроизводимости простого вопроса и я касался вопроса его удаления, только после доведения ответа до автора с помощью комментария.

---

Я считаю, что данный вопрос заслуживает право на существование как и ответы на него и он будет отлично дополнять вышеуказанное обсуждение.

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать, там есть ответы на часть ваших вопросов: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616)

Comment: В целом у вас тут несколько слабосвязанных вопросов: про пользу сообществу, про конкуренцию с новичками, про «недостойные внимания» вопросы — сложно будет ответить на все сразу. Может быть, вы выделите главный?

Comment: Кстати, тонкий намёк, пока злые редакторы не пришли: [Приветствия, подписи, мольбы, благодарности, лирические отступления, истории из жизни](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/93/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7)

Comment: И благодарить тут принято плюсами, а не спасибами! Даже в комментариях. P.S. это не шутка! :)

Comment: @alexolut вы забыли добавить, что это одно из субъективных мнений, в том числе и ваше. Но не общее мнение :-P

Comment: @АлексейШиманский общие бывают только ответы, а иногда и вопросы. Мнения всегда субъективны.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @jfs, я опубликовал различия между публикациями.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Отвечайте на что хотите отвечать.**
Легких вопросов на всех хватит.
Не хотите отвечать на легкие - отвечайте на сложные, проблем-то.

**Новички прорвутся.**
Легкие вопросы потому и легкие, что встречаются постоянно. Как правило старичкам просто надоедает в 100500й раз отвечать на легкие вопросы и они отделываются ссылками на дубликаты и кратким комментарием. Потом иногда прибегает новичок, отвечает полно и получает заслуженную карму. А иногда не прибегает и вопрос остается без ответа.

**Если Вы хотите написать полный качественный ответ - пишите.**
Потом на него можно будет ссылаться, особенно когда надоест отвечать на одно и то же) Механизм дубликатов для того и сделан.
Полные качественные ответы все любят =).
Если ваш ответ прям очень хороший, но на него еще нет вопроса, можно даже самому вопрос написать. Самоответы - это вполне нормальный механизм.

Если Ваш ответ принял автор, значит автору **пользу ваш ответ уже принес,** так что да, нужен)

**Ответы на вопросы в комментариях - это спорная тема**.
Некоторые их не любят, считая что ответ должен был в ответе. Лично я, как и многие участники сообщества, частенько отвечаю на вопрос в комментариях когда хочу подсказать  направление, но мне лень отвечать полно и вдаваясь в детали. В любом случае если ваш комментарий прям сильно помог, его можно будет вынести в ответ.

Answer (score 12):

Ответ в комментариях означает, что тот, кто его дал - не считает его ответом. Фактически, это приглашение любому знакомому с темой новичку написать подробный ответ и получить за это репутацию.

Конкретно тот вопрос, на который вы сослались - не является бесполезным, не смотря на некоторые признаки такового. Дело в том, что там приведен полный текст ошибки вместе с ее кодом - а значит, такой вопрос будет довольно просто найти в гугле по этому самому тексту ошибки.

PS эталонный пример "глупого", "простого", "наивного", но качественного и полезного вопроса про сообщение об ошибке - знаменитый вопрос про [PHP с его T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592322/php-expects-t-paamayim-nekudotayim) (кстати, у нас его то ли еще не было, то ли уже потерли)

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Мнение

По моему мнению, для IT-сообщества в целом и Stack Overflow в частности было бы **лучше, если бы за правила хорошего тона для опытных участниц/участников считалось бы не отвечать быстро (например, в течение первого часа) на несложные на их взгляд вопросы, предоставив шанс ответить менее опытным коллегам**. Если же спустя какое-то время никто не ответил либо поступившие ответы отличаются низким качеством, — приступаем.

В [**теме**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/sublime-text/topusers), где с отрывом являюсь участником с наибольшим числом баллов, так и делаю.

---

### 2. Аргументы

1. **Главный**. Более активное вовлечение новичков в процесс ответов на Stack Overflow, набирание ими опыта. Не нашёл статистики, но визуально кажется, что активно отвечающих здесь даже менее сотни, а должно быть побольше.

   2. **Побочный**. Разгрузка опытных участниц/участников. В целом, вероятнее, что им интереснее отвечать на более сложные вопросы; зачем же тратить своё время на простые.

---

### 3. Примечания

1. Надеюсь, на уровне правил никто никогда не запретит отвечать; предложение носит рекомендательный характер, оно, скорее, из морально-этической сферы.
2. Если хочется дать детальный и развёрнутый ответ, ничто не должно останавливать.
3. Отнюдь не уверен, что набивающие репутацию, согласятся со мной.

---

### 4. Ответы на некоторые контраргументы

#### 1. Новые отвечающие прорвутся

По личному опыту — это заблуждение.

я прочитал книги по регулярным выражениям, захотелось попробовать себя на практике, отвечая на вопросы по метке [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f). Но опытные участники то и дело опережали меня. Чтобы не написать ерунду, мне необходимо было почитать, где-то проверить правильность моих суждений; у них же опыта — как участия на Stack Overflow, так и в теме, — гораздо больше, и для соответствующего правилам ответа на простой вопрос им достаточно его увидеть. **Опытные участники за редким исключением всегда отвечают быстрее**. Плюс, если говорить об опыте по теме, мне нужно было проверить правильность моих суждений, освежить в памяти прочитанное, — им же для ответа на лёгкий вопрос достаточно взгляда.

По распространённым меткам, когда ответы от умудрённых опытом пользовательниц/пользователей следуют мгновенно, «пробиться» новым отвечающим довольно проблематично. Считаю это серьёзной проблемой для Stack Oveflow — одной из причин недостаточного притока новых отвечающих.

#### 2. От большего количества ответов от новичков Stack Overflow потеряет в качестве

Здесь принято ставить плюсы и минусы. Да, существует такое отвратительное явление, как [**неаргументированные минусы**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/199934), но в целом можно сказать, что система работает: качество ответа в целом коррелирует с его оценкой. Плохой ответ редко заплюсовывают, как верно и обратное. Если малоопытные участницы/участники будут давать некачественные ответы, их будут минусовать. Здесь не дадут плохим ответам долго продержаться.

#### 3. Stack Overflow недосчитается новых участников

Т.е. если сразу никто не будет отвечать, все новички разбегутся.

1. Отвечающие Stack Overflow не получают денег, никто не обязан быстро отвечать. Если у автора вопроса «горит», задать вопрос на Stack Overflow — не оптимальный путь. Лучше обратиться на фриланс-биржи; вот от людей, которым ты платишь со своего кармана, уже можно что-то требовать.
2. Q&A сайты держатся на отвечающих, именно они основа Stack Overflow. Создавать условия для роста одного хорошего отвечающего, не чинить ему препятствий, считаю, много лучшим, нежели сожалеть о людях, которые уходят с сайта, если им не ответили через минуту.
3. Опять же исключение: если считаете, что помимо Вас на вопрос вряд ли найдутся желающие отвечать, — например, никто больше не отвечает по редко используемой метке, — пишите ответ. Иначе правда авторы вопросов по метке разбегутся. Но по распространённым меткам желающих ответить хватает.

---

### 5. Старые вопросы

Ещё раз напишу, что тема заслуживает внимания.

1. Сложилась такая, по моему мнению, не лучшая тенденция: ответы на только что заданные вопросы плюсуют гораздо активнее ответов на древние. У меня был случай, когда получил плюсов больше, чем минут гуглил; на другой же вопрос, старый, готовил ответ несколько вечеров, в итоге он так и не получил ни балла репутации.
2. Среди старых неотвеченных вопросов мне попадались вопросы разной степени сложности. Предположу, что и по меткам найдётся на что поотвечать как опытным, так и не очень участницам/участникам.

Полагаю, помимо [**имеющихся мер**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838/199934) нужно предпринимать дополнительные, дабы отвечали не только лишь на текущие вопросы.

Comment: вводить искусственные ограничения для *старичков* может обернуться оттоком данного *пласта* сообщества что будет более печально чем не дать *новичку* ответить. если *ваша* цель получение *репы* то получение её не так уж и трудно: надо только задаться целью

Comment: @Bald, см. 3.1. Спасибо.

Comment: потом найдется *ситх* который возведет вашу рекомендацию в абсолют :). отвечаю на те вопросы на которые хочу ответить. и да репа не самое главное, разве мы здесь собрались не для того что бы *сделать мир лучше* ;)

Comment: Неоднозначно, содержит взаимоисключающие параграфы, мысль не устаканилась. То вы радеете за рост хорошего отвечающего, то хотите чтобы человек не разбирающийся в регулярках и подолгу гуглящий дал бы ответ быстрее и лучше, чем разбирающийся в теме? Когда вы станете специалистом -  от обратного будете выть: мол, засилья нет от плохих отвечающих, которые рвутся побыстрее дать плохой ответ. Выше ответы [1](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4581/213987) и [2](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4600/213987), что ветераны даже ответы порой не пишут, отдают на откуп новичкам. Мало?

Comment: @СашаЧерных "Если же спустя какое-то время никто не ответил либо поступившие ответы отличаются низким качеством" - то, что поступившие ответы не отличаются качеством - не помешает топикастеру схватить наихудший из них, применить и штампануть на него зеленую галку. И после этого никогда на SO больше не возвращаться.

Comment: "если бы за правила хорошего тона для опытных участниц/участников считалось бы не отвечать быстро" — на редкость деструктивное предложение. Вы фактически предлагаете, чтобы ответы писали менее компетентные люди. Ответы будут просто хуже. Много раз видел ситуацию, о которой пишет @PashaPash: ТС лепит галочку на очень плохой ответ просто потому, что он появился раньше. Так что наоборот, хорошие ответы нужно писать как можно скорее.

Comment: К тому же, эксперты часто соревнуются, кто напишет ответ быстрее, полнее и лучше. Эта соревновательность приносит удовольствие, которое является одной из немногих наград за участие в работе сайта. Вынужденное ожидание демотивирует экспертов и оттолкнет их от сайта, как выше уже написал @Bald

Comment: @NickVolynkin А если написать сначала быстрый ответ, а потом его дополнить? Так второй человек не будет тратить время на дублирующий ответ.

Comment: @Alex78191 на enSO это называют fastest gun in the west. Поищите на общей Мете. У меня сейчас связь плохая, сам не найду.

Comment: @NickVolynkin https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem?s=1|37.9748