# Какова реальная польза дубликатов?

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

Человек задал вопрос, который уже неоднократно задавали. Этот вопрос практически тут же отметили как дубликат к уже существующему вопросу. Как ситуацию рассматриваю я:

- Автор вопроса, вероятно, чувствует вину из за того, что задал заведомо плохой (бесполезный) (с точки зрения сайта) вопрос (из этого следует, что его желание задать новый вопрос поубавится)
- Знаний в сообществе за счет новых ответов от этого явно не прибавляется (а расширение базы знаний, насколько я знаю, основная цель ресурса)
- Вряд ли другие участники сообщества захотят теперь на этот вопрос отвечать

Из последнего пункта явно следует:

- Участники лишаются возможности повысить свою репутацию (что сделать итак довольно непросто, если учесть *относительно* небольшие размеры и активность нашего сообщества, а также тот факт, что вопросы, впоследствии становящиеся популярными и способные принести участникам обсуждения баллы репутации, задаются не так уж и часто)
- Ресурс лишается новых знаний. Согласитесь, вполне реальна ситуация, когда новичок на сайте (да и не только) оказывается экспертом, способным раскрыть об уже, казалось бы, вдоль и поперек разжеванном вопросе какие-то ранее неизвестные нюансы, подробности
- Кроме того, каждый вопрос по-своему уникален. Иногда стоит обратить задавшему вопрос человеку его внимание буквально на какую-то мелочь, чтобы он сразу понял, в чем кроется ответ на его вопрос, в то время как "заплюсованные" ответы на вопросы, к которым часто отсылают дубликатами, довольно сухи и обычно являются очень общими

Еще один пункт касается сугубо меня (хотя, возможно, со мной кто-нибудь согласится). Лично я замечал, что, когда мой вопрос отмечают, как дубликат к ранее заданному, то желание изучить проблему и прочесть ответы на "главный" вопрос намного меньше, чем когда я получаю ответ на вопрос, который задал я.

---

Также на этот вопрос стоит посмотреть с точки зрения ищущего человека. Обычно, когда ищешь ответ на какой-то популярный вопрос, например, в Google, то в выдаче на одной из верхних строчек находится ссылка на SO (SO, ruSO, непринципиально). При этом остальные ссылки в выдаче либо ведут вообще на другие, несвязанные ресурсы, либо, изредка, тоже на SO, но при этом чаще всего ни на один из вопросов, отмеченных дубликатом к наиболее популярной ссылке в выдаче (на SO). К чему я это?

К тому, что **я не понимаю смысл механизма дубликатов как таковых**.

Может быть, вопрос, отмеченный дубликатом, в дальнейшем закрывается (я просто не знаю)? Или удаляется? Тогда зачем они нужны? Не закрывается и не удаляется? Тогда, опять же, зачем они нужны? Какую пользу несут эти вопросы (см. пункты выше)?

Можно возразить и сказать, что на эти вопросы все еще можно ответить, даже несмотря на то, что они отмечены дубликатом. Допустим. Но какой в этом смысл? Во-первых, вряд ли кто станет это делать (см. выше). А даже если станет, то такие вопросы обычно не находятся простым поиском в интернете (см. выше), а если и удалось найти, то каков шанс того, что человек станет читать ответы, написанные под этим вопросом, а не под тем, который помечен как "главный", на который "уже отвечали"?

---

И да, в вопросе я говорю об абстрактном человеке и об абстрактном вопросе (кроме тех случаев, где я уточнил, что речь идет конкретно обо мне, естественно). Просто **пытаюсь разобраться** "со стороны". Со стороны наблюдателя и обывателя.

Comment: Ассоциация — это связь вопросов между сайтами, в частности между ruSO и enSO. Дубликаты — одинаковые по сути вопросы в пределах одного сайта, их принято закрывать, чтобы появлялась ссылка на первичный вопрос. Подправьте текст сообщения с учетом этих знаний, чтобы не возникало недопонимания.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У дубликатов много пользы.

1. Дубликаты устраняют родовую травму всех технических форумов - посыл новичков в поиск. Знакома ли вам ситуация когда вы ищите ответ на вопрос, находите 100 разных обсуждений, и в каждом из них вас посылают обратно в поиск?

   **Механизм же дубликатов направляет сразу на нужный вопрос как автора, так и последующих пришедших из поиска посетителей.**
2. Дубликаты позволяют экспертам не тратить силы в сотый раз отвечая на одно и то же. Читаете вопрос новичка и понимаете что очередной раз какой-то нуб не освоил азы и спрашивает то же самое что было уже сто раз спрошено? Надо просто найти любой из прошлых разов и ткнуть новичка в ту сторону.

   Если вопрос уже задавался - то новый вопрос надо сделать дубликатом к старому. Если такого вопроса еще не задавалось - то уж первый раз-то можно и ответить какую бы ерунду не спрашивали.

   **Дубликаты снижают агрессию экспертов к вопросам начинающих**
3. Многие вопросы можно спросить разными словами - а поисковики не понимают смысла вопросов, для поисковиков важны буквы в словах. Поэтому сеошники говорят: надо писать ключевые слова чтобы поисковики могли найти ваш текст, даже если текст из-за этого уродуется.

   **Дубликаты работают вместо SEO, давая поисковикам разные формулировки одного и того же вопроса.**

Comment: `Дубликаты позволяют экспертам не тратить силы в сотый раз отвечая на одно и то же` - а по факту в 90% случаев всё равно отвечают)) Особенно учитывая, что поиск тут некудышный.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну, свой-то собственный ответ всегда можно найти

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 1- гугл никто не отменял (отчасти поэтому нет инициативы внутренний поиск улучшать, так как внешние поисковики хорошо справляются) 2- достаточно одного голоса "эксперта" (обладателя золотого молота), чтобы вопрос закрыть как дубликат. Любой опытный участник может проголосовать вопрос как дубликат закрыть (1/5). По меньшей мере, в тех метках, которые я просматриваю, с *точными* дубликатами проблем нет (есть другие проблемы с качеством у большинства вопросов).

Comment: @jfs да уж , гугл "хороший помощник" искать темы "Помогите, проблема в коде", которыми пестрят тут вопросы через один. Кстати это еще одна большая проблема СО. Причем, как я понимаю, именно русского. На английском сегменте таких сообщений меньше.. Решить бы эту проблему - было бы веселе жить однозначно..... Ну а участников с молотами раз два и обчелся и почти не ведут сейчас тут активную деятельность...Например по java если бы не ромб модера у ЮрийСпб  - то молотов на java вообще не было, хотя их не мало... кмк, с этим есть проблемы. Но решать её я конечно не буду))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хинт: надо искать не вопрос, а ответ. Кривой заголовок не помешает найти ответ если вы его помните.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну и, конечно же, вопрос можно переименовать если ответ к нему важен...

Answer (score 2):

> TL;DR Я в чате съехидничал, что этот  вопрос про дубликаты неплохо бы
>   прикрыть как дубликат. В вопросе ничего нового нет, разные части
>   ответа раскиданы по мете, поэтому ответ можете не читать –
>   это просто длинная компиляция из других ответов.

Ситуация, когда вопрос цитирую "практически тут же" прихлопнули как дубликат – это ситуация, когда вопрос задавали настолько неоднократно, настолько часто, что его помнят не только обладатели "золотых молотов", но и большая часть активистов.

В качестве примера посмотрите:

- [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/213987) – 182 дубликата по состоянию на сегодняший день
- [Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/213987) - 54 дубликата

Вы смотрите на ситуацию и пытаетесь "разобраться со стороны", но у вас неполная картина. В частности, вы не могли разбирать очередь на закрытие, да и вряд ли дежурили в чате, туда часто кидают вопросы, которые нужно побыстрее закрыть.

По моему опыту, человек, который приходит из поисковика с каким-то вопросом, на который уже многократно и часто отвечали вряд ли будет испытывать чувство вины.

Если вам интересно, то это скорее похоже на ваши собственные чувства, которые вы бы испытывали в подобной ситуации: психологи  называют это "проецированием", это совершенно нормальный и естественный психологический процесс в ситуации, когда у мозга не хватает данных и он достраивает недостающие, доставая детали из ранее испытанного опыта. Просто запомните две вещи: проекция включается, когда мало входных данных и невозможно спроецировать в другого человека тот опыт, который ты сам не испытывал.

Люди, которые приходят из поисковика и задают вопросы, которые отмечаются как дубликат как правило ленивы и эгоистичны и не пробуют сделать несколько разных запросов в поисковике и на сайте перед тем, как задавать новый вопрос.

Неважно, идёт ли речь о тривиальном вопросе или достаточно сложных вещах – профессионал как правило сделает несколько запросов, потому что понимает, что "все вопросы уже давно отвечены на so" (не верите – попробуйте сами, на en so по зрелым технологиям у вас так и будет) и шанс спросить что-то действительно новое низок. Новые вопросы возникают у тех, кто ходит тропами, которыми не ходят широкие массы и если не говорить о новаторах (это уже опытные специалисты), то в остатке это либо узкоспециализированные вопросы (их не закрывают дубликатами, а они висят неотвеченными), либо новички, которые используют технологию не так, как её задумывали создатели и не так, как рекомендуют бест практис. Как правило, это тупиковые пути, которые быстро закрывают дубликатами "ты туда не ходи, ты сюда ходи: по опыту говорю снег башка попадёт".

> – Доктор, когда я вот вот так вот делаю у меня болит..((
>
> – А вы вот вот так вот не делайте ))))

Уверяю вас, это очень ценно, когда вам очень быстро говорят, что в той стороне нет смысла тратить время и что вы не так применяете инструменты. Особенно, когда вы только начинаете осваивать новую для себя область у вас нет ещё своего опыта, который позволяет отсекать варианты-пустышки.

> Знаний в сообществе за счет новых ответов от этого явно не
>   прибавляется (а расширение базы знаний, насколько я знаю, основная
>   цель ресурса)

Расширение базы знаний действительно цель ресурса. При этом давайте определимся: для базы данных более ценно создание нового качественного контента, который будет пользоваться высоким спросом, а не триста вариантов материала на один и тот же новичковый вопрос.

Поэтому очень полезно закрывать вопросы, чтобы не тратить силы отвечающих на один и тот же отвеченный вопрос – отвечающих и так немного, специалисты – это один из наиболее ценных и ограниченных ресурсов на сайте.

Закрытие вопроса дубликатом ценно для того, чтобы дать поисковикам подсказки о вариациях вопроса. Один и тот же вопрос можно спросить разными словами, к одному и тому же вопросу можно придти разными путями. Поисковики ещё с ранних пор развития умеют строить графы ссылок и понимают, что вопрос, на который сослались сто раз нужно поднять выше в выдаче.

Для людей же стоит заметная плашка "на этот вопрос уже ответили: ".

> Вряд ли другие участники сообщества захотят теперь на этот вопрос
>   отвечать

Не совсем так. Как участник, который смотрит сайт в прямом эфире могу сказать, что перед закрытием очень часто успевают дать ответ, а то и не один. Это либо участники, которым ещё не надоели подобные частые вопросы (фактически они сами тренируют себя и это полезно), либо наши записные репофермеры.

Но многие не захотят отвечать на подобные вопросы (например – уже надоело отвечать на одно и то же) и это благо. Ресурс фокусирует усилия отвечающих там, где они более нужны. Участники отвечают на то, что им действительно интересно. Помню я сам как-то пытался отвечать на подобные тривиальные вещи, но быстро надоедает и начинаешь ждать действительно интересных вопросов.
А вообще на сайте вопросов много, [всем хватит](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4581/213987).

> Участники лишаются возможности повысить свою репутацию

Не лишаются. Я выше писал: пока соберётся пять голосов – уже успевают вкатить свою версию ответа, если хотят ответить и сразу играют на опережение (открытая форма ответа спасает или заранее удалённый ответ для последующего восстановления).

> Ресурс лишается новых знаний. Согласитесь, вполне реальна ситуация,
>   когда новичок на сайте (да и не только) оказывается экспертом,
>   способным раскрыть об уже, казалось бы, вдоль и поперек разжеванном
>   вопросе какие-то ранее неизвестные нюансы, подробности

Вот тут не соглашусь. Эксперт, который знает хорошие ньюансы ответа не будет задавать вопрос – а даст новый ответ в самый главный дубликат или хотя бы черкнёт комментарий под одним из ответов. Эксперт – этот тот самый человек, который получает "тысячу долларов за удар" (удар — доллар, остальное за "знал, куда ударить"). Я уверен: реальный профессионал не будет писать в каждый из ста дубликатов, он лениво ударит в одну-единственную точку если вдруг увидит слабину в эталлонном ответе.

> Кроме того, каждый вопрос по-своему уникален. Иногда стоит обратить
>   задавшему вопрос человеку его внимание буквально на какую-то мелочь,
>   чтобы он сразу понял, в чем кроется ответ на его вопрос

Угу. Для этого за глаза хватает и поля комментария. И комментарии у дубликатов не запрещены, не знали?

Отвлекусь на минутку от темы, бог с ними с дубликатами: существует масса вопросов, в которых ветераны дали ответ в комментариях, но всем лень скомпоновать в полноценный ответ. Могу сходу назвать несколько подобных участников, особенно почему-то по sql-меткам. Так вот не стесняйтесь [собирать ответы из комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4670/213987), если их поленились оформить.

Я вот к чему отвлёкся: существование подобных тем, где хватило комментария – самое явное подтверждение того факта, что на изъезженный вдоль и поперёк вопрос-дубликат достаточно поля комментария, чтобы дать намёк, обратить внимание на какую-то мелочь и т.п.

> К тому, что я не понимаю смысл механизма дубликатов как таковых.

Ещё раз в сжатой форме:

- Даёт плашку "этот вопрос ранее задавался: " и блок справа  – ссылки на смежные вопросы. Вдумчивый читатель может посмотреть множество похожих вопросов для изучения нюансов
- Даёт этот же граф кросс-ссылок поисковикам (гугл точно использует)
- Даёт n версий одного и того же заголовка вопроса: как бы ты не задал вопрос в поиске – всё равно тебя быстро и эффективно приведут к решению
- Фокусирует отвечающих отвечать на новые вопросы, а не мусолить старые

> Может быть, вопрос, отмеченный дубликатом, в дальнейшем закрывается (я
>   просто не знаю)? Или удаляется?  Не закрывается и не удаляется?

Если бы вы поискали ответ – то увидели бы, что на ваш вопросы уже есть ответы:

- [Почему некоторые вопросы отмечаются как дубликаты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)
- [Как работает удаление? Что может стать причиной удаления сообщения и что представляет собой процесс удаления? Каковы критерии для удаления?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/213987)

И ещё. Не испытывайте чувства вины – просто ищите ответы перед тем, как задавать вопрос. Это же первый пункт [справки "как задавать хорошие вопросы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Когда по вопросу видно, что человек не понимает, что именно нужно гуглить (такое бывает) достаточно намёка в комментариях, когда по вопросу видно (а это сразу видно), что топикстартер пытался найти ответ – повышается желание ответить на вопрос.

Comment: На последнюю часть: всегда ищу ответы сначала как в поисковике, так и в поиске ruSO. И в этот раз думал даже приложить ссылки на найденные на мой запрос вопросы, но посчитал, что такой необходимости не возникнет. Видимо, ошибся. Если учесть, что "схожесть" вопросов я определяю по заголовкам, то весьма логично то, что "Почему вопрос отмечаются как дубликаты" и "Какова польза дубликатов" для меня не равны.

Comment: А насчет всего остального я примерно понял вашу позицию. Если ваша позиция отражает позицию большинства участников сообщества, то, что ж. Мне с ней в любом случае придется смириться, даже если в каких-то моментах я не согласен. Но в целом - спасибо за ответ. Будет над чем подумать.

Comment: Я посмотрел ваши вопросы, поэтому знаю, что вы ищете. Но ответы пишутся не тем, кто спрашивает -- а тем, кто придёт потом из поиска, поэтому не принимайте на свой личный счёт, хорошо? Это вообще было нужно мне для создания линка на раздел "как задать хороший вопрос".

Comment: Разумеется. Благодарю за уделенное время.

Comment: *"Поисковики ещё с ранних пор развития умеют строить графы ссылок и понимают, что вопрос, на который сослались сто раз нужно поднять выше в выдаче."* - вообще-то, гугл был первым и именно на этом взлетел

Comment: Я не согласен, что на все вопросы уже отвечены даже по зрелым технологиям. Особенно на ruSO.