# Правки на странице "Выборы модераторов сообщества"

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, локализация, модерация

[Страница "Выборы модераторов сообщества"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election)

- Нужен перевод для результата выборов 2017-ого года
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Перевод нужен такой, чтобы заменить текст для всех результатов, а то на каждый год свой текст написан. Думаю было бы красиво и правильно, если бы текст был одинаково переведён для всех результатов. Можно взять по сути любой из 3-х текстов, потому не буду предлагать новый перевод, а просто объявлю голосование в комментариях, конечно, можно и свой вариант :)

1. Текст за 2015-ый код

   > 1,946 голосовали пользователи, имевшие на это право, во время голосования сайт посетили 639 пользователей, 671 пользователей посетили страницу голосования, и 320 проголосовало
2. Текст за 2019-ый код

   > 5,747 могло проголосовать, 2,091 посетили сайт во время выборов, 1,690 посетили страницу выборов, из них 798 проголосовали
3. Текст за 2020-ый код

   > 8,368 избирателей имели право проголосовать, во время выборов сайт посетили 1,796 участников, 1,905 посетили страницу выборов, и 634 проголосовало

Comment: + За 1-ый вариант

Comment: + За 2-ой вариант

Comment: + За 3-ий вариант (не могу ставить плюсик, но я за этот вариант)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - Может мне просто удалить вопрос, т.к. ничего нового вроде нет у меня?

Comment: [обычно удалять не стоит](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6687/176217)